# Access Method from FileSystemWatcher Event Handler in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to access a method from inside an event handler using the FileSystemWatcher. It seems like variations of this question have been asked but I sure can't seem to use any of them to answer to this point. In the code below I want to be able to access ReadNoteFile from OnChanged but cannot. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void CreateFileWatcher(string path)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = path;

        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }


public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("New note has arrived!");

        //run ReadNoteFile here

    }

public void ReadNoteFile(string path)
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
```

Comment: Can you not make ReadNoteFile static?

Comment: Don't make OnChanged static

Comment: Ok I feel rather dumb but yes making ReadNoteFile static as it should have been solves this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileSystemEventHandler` constructor expects `(object, IntPtr)` arguments.

I suggest skipping the creation of another object and pass a lambda directly (as is usual practice nowadays in this scenario):

```
watcher.Changed += delegate() { MessageBox.Show("New note has arrived!"); };
```

---

#### [FileSystemWatcher#Changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed?view=netframework-4.7.2)